# Does ETC have wallet which can use multi-signature wallet contract like Ethereum Wallet For ETH

Tags: wallets, ethereum-classic

Does ETC have wallet which can use multi signature wallet contract like Ethereum Wallet For ETH?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has. Technically, ETC is very similar to ETH since it was a fork of it (-> see the TheDAO fork).